# How to find all WGS assemblies accessions of a species

Tags: assembly, phylogenetics, wgs

#### Some background

Similar to the OP of https://www.biostars.org/p/377840/, I would like to programmatically BLAST a sequence to a local database of all WGS assemblies.
Since this isn't feasible for the average biology lab server (correct me if I am wrong), I plan to use [ncbi-acc-download](https://github.com/kblin/ncbi-acc-download) to download all WGS assemblies of the species of interest (not a popular species like E. coli, so it should be feasible). Then, I will create a BLAST database for the downloaded assemblies and BLAST the sequence to it.

#### My question

How can I find all WGS assemblies accessions of a species?

---

My current plan is to search the [NCBI Assembly database](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly) using [Entrez](https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.Entrez.html) and a search term such as `"wgs"[Properties] AND txid1337[orgn:exp]`.
**EDIT: IIUC, this approach might miss some WGS assemblies.** See [my answer](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/14749/4868).

I am worried (and thus ask for your help) this isn't the right approach because there seem to be at least 3 other places in which assemblies can be found:

- The assembly_summary.txt files that are described in https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/README_assembly_summary.txt.
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/wgs/. **This is the one I am most worried about.** Both because it seems to have much more entries, and also because https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genbank/wgs/ says: "The public WGS projects are at the [list of WGS projects](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/wgs/) ."
- [taxid2wgs.pl](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/blast/WGS_TOOLS/). (As mentioned in https://www.biostars.org/p/377840/#471535, this one seems to miss some assemblies.)

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be WGS assemblies that can't be found in [NCBI Assembly database](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly), e.g.: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/1779902990. I guess that such assemblies also cannot be found in The assembly_summary.txt files that are described in https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/README_assembly_summary.txt.

My current best guess is that each WGS assembly has a "WGS master record" in [NCBI Nuccore database](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore). To find all WGS assemblies of a taxon whose uid in [NCBI Taxonomy database](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/taxonomy) is `1337`, search [NCBI Nuccore database](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore) using [Entrez](https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.Entrez.html) and the search term `"wgs master"[Properties] AND txid1337[orgn:exp]`.